# Oracle: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, database, plsql

After invoking this line of code:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE user.table DISABLE CONSTRAINT user.trigger;';
```

I receive an error:

> ORA-00933 SQL Command not properly Ended

Answer (score 1):

Try dropping the semicolon in statement to be executed:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE user.table DISABLE CONSTRAINT user.trigger';
```

Comment: Are you sure? I've just checked it, and it seems to work OK for me

Comment: I know where was my mistake. Trigger is not a constraitnt. It should be ALTER TRIGGER user.trigger disable;

Comment: This was exactly my stupid mistake in a JDBC command string. Once I removed the semicolon it worked. Thus +1 to your answer!